# Error while getting Uber AccessToken in ios

Tags: ios, swift, access-token, uber-api

I am trying to get AccessToken From **UberRides**. For that I followed Uber developer portal tutorial. But I'm not getting accessToken from `LoginManager` class while login. Here is my Code.

```
@IBAction func getRide(sender: UIButton) {

    let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.login(requestedScopes:[.RideWidgets], presentingViewController: self, completion: { accessToken, error in
        // Completion block. If accessToken is non-nil, you’re good to go
        print("::AccessToken::")
        print(accessToken)
        print("::Error::")
        print(error)
    })

}
```

But I'm getting following log while clicking on my custom button.

> ::AccessToken:: 
> nil 
> ::Error:: 
> Optional(Error
>   Domain=com.uber.rides-ios-sdk.ridesAuthenticationError Code=20 "A
>   network error occured." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=A network
>   error occured.})

I checked and my internet connection is working properly. But still this error is occurring.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: It has nothing to do with your connection. It's a authentication error: **ridesAuthenticationError**. Are you sure your sending the correct details?

Comment: Yes, I'm passing correct details in `LoginManagerViewController` presented by Uber

Comment: Are you seeing the login page at all or does it immediately fail with that error? Also, what version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes, that was done by one of my colleague. I requested him to post answer here.